# how to format and display date from database using resultset

Tags: java, jdbc

I've written a query to get data from database.

```
String Query = "Select ID, NAME, ADDRESS, CONTACTNUMBER,DISEASE,DOCASSIGN,JOINING,ROOMASSIGN from patient";
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(Query);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

            while (rs.next()) {
        %>
        <tr>
            <td><%=rs.getInt("ID")%></td>
            <td><%=rs.getString("NAME")%></td>
            <td><%=rs.getString("ADDRESS")%></td>
            <td><%=rs.getInt("CONTACTNUMBER")%></td>
            <td><%=rs.getString("DISEASE")%></td>
            <td><%=rs.getInt("DOCASSIGN")%></td>
            <td><%=rs.getDate("JOINING")%></td>
            <td><%=rs.getString("ROOMASSIGN")%></td>
        </tr>
        <%
            }
        %>
```

I'm able to display all the date in jsp table with no issues, but the date i'm displaying below statement.

```
<td><%=rs.getDate("JOINING")%></td>
```

the output i get is as below.

```
2015-07-01
```

but i want it in the below format (MM/dd/yyyy)

```
07-01-2015
```

please let me know how can i get this.

Thanks

Comment: Stop using scriptlets, put your JDBC code into Java classes (servlets), learn to use the JSP EL and the JSTL, and use the JSTL <fmt:formatDate> tag. You're coding your JSPs as if we were stil in 1999.

Answer (score 1):

Use SimpleDateFormat to format date in java:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
df.format(rs.getDate("JOINING"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use format function in sql to format your date

```
FORMAT(JOINING,'MM/YY/YYYY') 
"Select ID, NAME, ADDRESS, CONTACTNUMBER,DISEASE,DOCASSIGN,FORMAT(JOINING,'MM/YY/YYYY'),ROOMASSIGN from patient"
```

Comment: Hi, this is giving me `javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "FORMAT": invalid identifier
`

Comment: what database ur using